# How can I design alerts rather than the one which is working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'post/add_review/',
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(e) {
      if (e.status)
      {
       alert("Review Success") 
    }
```

This is how I am displaying alert. How can I change this alert box and use another alert which is designed

```
<style>
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

.closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
</style>

<div class="alert">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>
```

How can I able to use this alert rather the standard alert in html?

Comment: `alert("Review Success")` -- the one which you see using this statement isn't customizable. It is native to the browser, and cannot be customized using JS or CSS.

Comment: `$( ".alert" ).html( "Review Success" );`

Comment: how can I able to customize

Comment: If you want to use this html.. `<div class="alert">` just replace the `alert` with `$( ".alert" ).html( "Review Success" );`

Comment: Be aware that you aren't implementing a fully interchangeable `alert()` replacement because native `window.alert()` function is a browser's native implementation which **pauses javascript event-loop** so when you call `window.alert()` no other javascript is executed until user closes it. And unfortunately there is no way to achieve the same behaviour just with javascript. This is not fatal if you are aware of it, but it can bring you some headache if you unconsciously rely on that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class `hidden` and use `addClass/removeClass` to toggle the display of the container.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list', // dummy url
  //data: data,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(e) {
    if (e.status) {
      // if true then show the div container and append the status in this div
      $(".alert").removeClass("hidden").html(e.status);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert hidden">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to show/update your message:

```
<div class="alert">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>


 $.ajax({
      url: 'post/add_review/',
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(e) {
      if (e.status)
      {
       $( ".alert" ).html( "Review Success" );
      }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI Dialog.

https://jsfiddle.net/tanvisurve/ge2o3573/2/

```
<body>
<div>
<input id="txtInput" name="txtInput" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="btnGo" name="btnGo">Go</button>
</div>
<div id="divModalDialog" title="Go" hidden="hidden"></div>
</body>

$(function(){
 $("#btnGo").click(function(){
  $("#divModalDialog").html($("#txtInput").val());
  $( "#divModalDialog" ).dialog();
 });
});
```

It might solve your problem.